# Difference between "work alongside you" and "work alongside with you"

Tags: prepositions

Is there a difference between

> **work alongside you** vs **work alongside with you**

The definition of "alongside" indicates **with** is not needed.

> definition
>
> - next to
> - in company with

But it's not uncommon to see/hear the phrase "work alongside with you".

Are both expressions interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that *work along side you* can be considered common. In fact, I've never heard or seen it.

---

The following are possible:

> I work alongside you.
>   I work with you.
>   I work alongside **her** with you.
>   I work with **her** alongside you.

---

Here's what [Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work%20alongside%20you%2C%20work%20with%20you%2C%20work%20alongside%20with%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20alongside%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20with%20you%3B%2Cc0) shows:

[image: work alongside with you]

*Work alongside with you* is so uncommon that it's not even shown on the graph.

Also of note is that *work with you* seems much more common than *work alongside you*.

Comment: Excellent ! This is what I was looking for. I forgot about the "Ngram" but did a google trend search "work alongside you" vs. "work alongside with", it shows a slightly different plot though. But it may be not a correct comparison as "work alongside with" may pick up terms appropriate in different contexts.

Comment: @BChen It's easy to pick up out-of-context false positives from the NGram Viewer. it can be tricky to formulate the right queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think many people would consider **alongside with** a little clumsy.